# Docker Apache Extra White Space makes PHP page responded as blank page

Tags: php, apache

We are running docker with php:7.4-apache image.
The problem we are facing is ... if there are extra space before `<?php` or after `?>` php script tag, the php page stop working and showing only blank page. The error normally shown is

```
output is already started at line xx.
```

It usually cause problem with session read/write operation.
We need to remove the white space manually from each php page.
Is there any option to ignore the white space for such docker running environment.

Comment: I think you've run into a common PHP error – [see here](https://thecancerus.com/warning-headers-already-sent/). This isn't related to the fact PHP is containerised, as far as I can tell. PHP should be fine with whitespace before and after the tags, so this is likely an error in the application somewhere. Was the application working on another host? What version of PHP have you come from, and which version are you using in the container?

Comment: I am using CakePHP. It can run perfectly in other environment such as Wamp, Xampp. However, when I put the application on docker, the leading and trailing whitespace before and after PHP tag giving me error.